# List to DropDown list in Yii

Tags: php, yii, html.dropdownlistfor, yii-chtml

Please help with this code:

```php
<ul class="activity-projects">
    <?php foreach ($ownProjects as $userProject) : ?>
    <li>
        <a class="<?php echo ($userProject->id == $project_id) ? 'active' : '';?>"
            href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('user/activity', array(
                'user_id'=>$user->id,
                'project_id'=>$userProject->id,
                'date'=>$date)
            ); ?>"><?php echo $userProject->name; ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php foreach ($projects as $userProject) : ?>
    <li>
        <a class="<?php echo ($userProject->project_id == $project_id) ? 'active' : '';?>"
            href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('user/activity', array(
                'user_id'=>$user->id,
                'project_id'=>$userProject->project->id,
                'date'=>$date)
            ); ?>"><?php echo $userProject->project->name; ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

How to change it to dropdown list, using `CHtml::dropDownList`. Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution finally helps me:

```
<?php  $options = array();
  foreach ($projects as $userProject) :
    $options[$userProject->id] = $userProject->project->name;
  endforeach;

  echo CHtml::dropDownList('selectName', '1', $options); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define a key-value array like this:

```
$options = array();
<?php foreach ($ownProjects as $userProject) 
    array_push($options, array($userProject->id => $userProject->name));
?>

 echo CHtml::dropDownList('seletName', '1', $options);
```

This will be produced an html `<select>` tag with "seletcName" name. And also option with value "1" will be selected option. You can use your desired value for first and second parameters.
Also you can use [CActiveForm#dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dropDownList-detail) for this purpose.

Comment: @kirbrown Did you try my solution?

Comment: Solution is great, thanks, but I don't know much about Yii framework, so I can't paste my code above right in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your form, use the form dropDownList() function.

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
               $model,
               'project_id',
               CHtml::listData(OwnProjects::model()->findAll(),
                   'id', 'name'),
               array('empty' => '(Select project)','class'=>"form-control")
          );
?>
```

From your example, it looks like OwnProjects is not a model on its own, but a subset of a model. You can customise the query

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList(
               $model,
               'project_id',
               CHtml::listData(OwnProjects::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('user_id'=> Yii:app()->user->id),
                   'id', 'name'),
               array('empty' => '(Select project)','class'=>"form-control")
          );
?>
```